# Does a negative exponent distribute?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

This should be simple but I am confused.

$$(a^{-1}+b^{-1})^{-1}$$

How is the negative exponent distributed to the terms inside the parentheses? If they were being multiplied it would be simple but they are being added and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your cannot distribute exponents across parentheses to terms being added or subtracted.

Comment: `How is the negative exponent distributed to the terms inside the parentheses?` Why does "*negative*" matter here? How would you "*distribute*" a positive exponent like $(a^2+b^2)^2$ for example? Short answer is that exponents do not "*distribute*" over addition, doesn't matter whether positive or negative.

Comment: I want to write it without the negative exponent, or apply it to the parentheses not distribute

Comment: @dxiv: A possible answer to that would be that that's what the binomial theorem theorem is for, but it works only for nonnegative integer exponents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^{-1}=\frac1a $$ no matter what a is. a could be an expression or a number, it doesn't matter; the -1 exponent just puts it as a denominator in a fraction with numerator 1.

Thus the answer is 
$$\frac1{\frac1a +\frac1b}=\frac1{\frac{a+b}{ab}}=\frac{ab}{a+b}$$

Answer (score 1):

Exponentiation of real (or complex) numbers never distributes over addition of real (or complex) numbers.

For positive natural numbers, this is because:

$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^{k}$$

This is called the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and you can read about it―and its extension to non-positive and non-natural values―at the linked provided herebefore.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a^{-1}+b^{-1})^{-1} = \frac 1 {\frac 1 a + \frac 1 b}= \frac {ab}  {a+b}.$$